# How to invoke an RPC call in a Python script residing on a windows server from a Linux client

Tags: python, rpc

I want to invoke a python function residing on windows 7 machine through RPC call from a linux client. Please suggest some methods. Thanks

Comment: A simple example of xmlrpc is provided in the python documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example

Answer (score 0):

[XML-rpc](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) is build into python, and very simple to use.

Comment: I tried xml-rpc but there i am not able to find any API in it to Login to the windows machine i.e to give username, password

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question. xmlrpc runs as a server, accessible via the network and does not need windows credentials to work. It seems you are asking about something else

Comment: Oh is it. So xml-rpc does not require windows credentials to work? First even i thought so but then when i used it, it gives the error target machine is actively refusing the connection or something. so i thought credentials are necessary. Pls tell what to do?

Comment: "arget machine is actively refusing the connection" suggests that the windows firewall is blocking the port of the xmlrpc server

Comment: Please ensure your XMLRPC server is running on Windows. You can check connectivity from linux using the telnet command like this: "telnet IP_OF_WIN_PC SERVED_RPC_PORT"

Comment: Ensure also that you not start the server on "localhost", but on the public available IP address (localhost-servers are not available for non-local clients)